# Is there a way to determine the current breakpoint in Bootstrap without relying on Javascript?

Tags: bootstrap-4

There many examples (hacks) to determine the current breakpoint using Javascript, but I am in need of a solution that leverages CSS.

Comment: you can check the css file to know about the break-points... why do you want to determine something which is hardcoded in boostrap.css file ?

Comment: You need to clarify the question. Bootstrap breakpoints are based on **CSS** media queries. Why do you want to determine the current breakpoint? For example, you can show/hide elements on specific breakpoints without CSS: https://www.codeply.com/go/yv4rEjdwdd

Comment: @Zim that you for pointing that out. Using the Bootstrap utility classes (getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/borders), can help. To answer Akber question, I am creating custom style for multiple widgets in a single page. The widgets are always visible, but some widgets maintain their style for small and medium resolution, but in some cases the style should be the same for medium and large resolutions. In short, I find myself using a lot of media query to chase portions of the design of a single widget.

Answer (score 4):

If this is a tool you need for designing your layout, then you can create labels keyed to display only at the specific breakpoint.

```
<div class="d-block d-sm-none">xs</div>
<div class="d-none d-sm-block d-md-none">sm</div>
<div class="d-none d-md-block d-lg-none">md</div>
<div class="d-none d-lg-block d-xl-none">lg</div>
<div class="d-none d-xl-block">xl</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of a simple CSS solution to determine current breakpoint, a possible approach will be to create the logic to calculate the breakpoint in Javascript, and link the code to the page using

```
    <link rel="import" href="breakpoints.html">
```

"breakpoints.html" should add a CSS class to the page BODY tag indicating the current breakpoint. e.g.:

```
   <body class="breakpoint-md">...</body>
```

In that way the logic to determine the current breakpoint is outside of the page, and can be reused in any project, but you can simply add a "suffix" to your CSS selectors, instead of using complicated media query. e.g.:

```
.breakpoint-md #widget {
    color: red;
}

.breakpoint-lg #widget {
    color: blue;
}
```

Here is the content of **breakpoint.html**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

(function($) {

    function isBreakPoint(size) {
        var value = window.getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--breakpoint-' + size);
        var matched = window.matchMedia("(min-width: "+ value +")").matches;
        return matched;
    }

    $( window ).resize(function() { 
        if(isBreakPoint('xs')) {
            $(document.body).addClass('breakpoint-xs').removeClass('breakpoint-sm breakpoint-md breakpoint-lg breakpoint-xl');
        }
        if(isBreakPoint('sm')) {
            $(document.body).addClass('breakpoint-sm').removeClass('breakpoint-xs breakpoint-md breakpoint-lg breakpoint-xl');
        }
        if(isBreakPoint('md')) {
            $(document.body).addClass('breakpoint-md').removeClass('breakpoint-xs breakpoint-sm breakpoint-lg breakpoint-xl');
        }
        if(isBreakPoint('lg')) {
            $(document.body).addClass('breakpoint-lg').removeClass('breakpoint-xs breakpoint-sm breakpoint-md breakpoint-xl');
        }

        if(isBreakPoint('xl')) {
            $(document.body).addClass('breakpoint-xl').removeClass('breakpoint-xs breakpoint-sm breakpoint-md breakpoint-lg');
        }
    });

    $( window ).resize();

})(window.jQuery);
</script>
```

Here is how the BODY tag is modified:
[image]
To add **breakpoints.html** to your page, anywhere in your HTML code you can add:

```
<link re="import" href="breakpoints.htmt"/>
```